# Share entire view controller as image or PDF

Tags: ios, swift, pdf-generation, share

I am trying to share the entire view controller as an image or a PDF. Below I have the current code I am using to share the view controller as an image but I am not sure how to modify the bounds in order to save the entire view controller, including content that is off the screen. I also do not know how to give an option to save as image or PDF.

```
@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    self.view.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [img!], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I think I saw this somewhere else on stackoverflow recently. Ill look for the answer but if I remember properly, you'll want to change the `bounds.size` to the total size you need to capture, then set the point to start looking at outside of your view in order to capture all of it.

Comment: Now just to make sure, You're not trying to capture a table or collection view off screen right? Because the data doesn't load until it's on the screen if almost every case.

Comment: Yes I am trying to capture a table view that is off the screen, so it may be easier to just not use a tableview, would a scrollview allow me to capture what's off of the screen?

Comment: Yes. But if your data gets too big it will cause problems

Comment: I tried it with a scrollview but it still only captures what is on the screen, let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds is the issue but everything I try to change it to causes errors

Comment: You need to set the bounds to the size of the `scrollview` not the `view`

Comment: Can you show the errors?

Comment: let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 2000)

And got error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: How do I set the bounds to the scrollview no matter what size I actually make it?

Comment: Okay, so I finally found what I read recently. I apologize for all of the wasted time. I'm going to put it as an answer below.

Comment: Okay I found a few different answers. The edit may be what you're looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

> EDITED: Try final answer listed at the bottom.

So to process a ScreenShot it has to be rendered in the graphics on the view. Except for when the app is using `SpriteKit`. You can get a good explanation [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448879/how-do-i-take-a-full-screen-screenshot-in-swift) but to surmise, the method in which you get a screenshot is by the `graphicsContext`. Anything not on screen is not in the `context` so it will not be available for a screenshot. However, graphics can be drawn outside of the view manually like with `SpriteKit`.

> If you're using `SpriteKit` you can do this (answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535962/spritekit-screenshot-of-view-off-screen)) :

```
func getScreenshot(scene: SKScene) -> UIImage {
    let bounds = self.scene!.view?.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds!.size, true, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    self.scene?.view!.drawViewHierarchyInRect(bounds!, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return screenshot;
}
```

> `let bounds = self.scene!.view?.bounds` this is what I saw that led me to comment earlier.

EDIT: To draw to the context try:

> EDIT: `view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)` found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46050451/9333764)
>   or `view.layer.draw(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)` found on the same page